# How do I restart Docker for Mac from the terminal?

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

Docker for Mac has a neat little 'restart' button in the dropdown from the whale icon in the menu bar.

I'd like to be able to restart Docker for Mac from the terminal, though. What command would I need to run?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Specifically for Docker for Mac, because it's a "GUI" app, there's a [workaround](http://osxdaily.com/2014/09/05/gracefully-quit-application-command-line/):

`osascript -e 'quit app "Docker"'`

Since you'd want to restart, here's the way to [open it from the command line](https://superuser.com/a/1107622/243446):

`open -a Docker`

There's probably a more symmetrical command to open using `osascript`, but the `open` command seems more common than the `osascript` one.

Comment: Nice. Here's the alias I've added to my bash profile: `alias docker_restart="osascript -e 'quit app \"Docker\"' && open -a Docker"
`

Comment: osascript? I don't have that command.

Comment: That was surprisingly simple. Thanks!

Comment: `open -a Docker` that's nice ;)

Comment: Looks to me that on MacOS 12.5, M1 Mac `osascript -e 'quit app "Docker"'` does a restart

Answer (score 46):

The following command worked for me:

```
killall Docker && open /Applications/Docker.app
```

Comment: My docker was stuck and this was the right solution.

Comment: Very useful when docker is stuck!

Answer (score 21):

Docker takes a while to initialize.

```
osascript -e 'quit app "Docker"'; open -a Docker ; while [ -z "$(docker info 2> /dev/null )" ]; do printf "."; sleep 1; done; echo ""
```

Answer (score 12):

Looks like there is no way to perform this.

I found an official answer for the same question in:

https://forums.docker.com/t/restart-docker-from-command-line/9420/2

Hope they include this feature soon.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am using ([source](https://forums.docker.com/t/restart-docker-from-command-line/9420/16)):

```
alias docker_restart="curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ \"openContainerView\": true }' -kiv --unix-socket ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/backend.sock http://localhost/engine/restart"
```