# How to restart Docker-for-mac with command?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-for-mac

I'm using Docker for mac. 
I'd like to restart this Docker-for-mac App with command on Terminal.
What's the command?
There was no documentation for this.
I had do restart it by clicking that button anytime that I needed to.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restart Docker for Mac from the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080887/how-do-i-restart-docker-for-mac-from-the-terminal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forcing Docker for Mac to re-read its config with

```
killall -HUP com.docker.hyperkit
```

might work - if it doesn't, please explain in more detail why you need to restart Docker in the first place.

Comment: I needed to restart Docker so it would pick up new CA certs that I had installed.

Comment: This command caused problems for me when running Docker Edge. I found a better way here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44555371/1827734

Answer (score 2):

For me I needed to restart Docker so I could install the new version

`killall Docker` did the trick.