# Docker cannot login to azurecr.io

Tags: azure, docker, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

On `Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4` (running on Mac OS 10.12.5) I'm having the following error when I run `docker login <proj>.azurecr.io`:

> Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot
>   connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the
>   docker daemon running?). Using system default:
>   https://index.docker.io/v1/

This is after I input the username and password that I retrived using `az acr`. I've done this same process in the past and now it's not working anymore.

How can I debug this and login/pull images again?

Comment: What is the result `service docker status`? Your docker daemon is running?

Comment: If possible you could restart your docker service, please refer to this similar issue. https://github.com/yegor256/rultor/issues/1041

Comment: maybe you are not part of the docker group? Does it work with `sudo docker login`?

Comment: Hi, does it work now?

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT I did not get a chance to check the status but I got it working. See my answer below

Comment: @sg I also add it a answer. It seems the issue did not happen on Mac. Hope it will help more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: I believe I just needed to restart Docker.

First, I turned on debugging by adding `{ "debug": true }` to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. Resource [here](https://success.docker.com/article/How_do_I_enable_%27debug%27_logging_of_the_Docker_daemon). This probably wasn't needed

Second, I restarted docker from the mac terminal with `osascript -e 'quit app "Docker"'` followed by `open -a Docker`, details found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080887/how-do-i-restart-docker-for-mac-from-the-terminal).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you need restart your docker service, please refer to this similar issue.

https://github.com/yegor256/rultor/issues/1041